# Assigning my own date to Date Column of format HH:MM:SSS.000 in Pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, datetimeindex

I have data logging to a csv file that has a timestmap in the form HH:MM:SSS.000.
[Raw Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe8aY.png) . I when I read this data into pandas via this line of code it is automatically adding today's date into the column from the parse_dates function ;

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('20-9-2019-ETH.csv', names=['Volume', 'Price', 'Time'],
                index_col=2, parse_dates=True)

df.head()

                          Volume    Price
Time        
2020-03-01 00:00:11.904  0.091683   217.60
2020-03-01 00:00:12.730  0.916826   217.60
2020-03-01 00:00:12.430  0.331441   217.60
2020-03-01 00:00:15.161  1.420000   217.59
2020-03-01 00:00:15.354  0.174274   217.57
```

What would I need to do so that I can specify what date it should be putting using instead of the day the file was created? Or maybe I can remove the date entirely and just have the timestamp there? Either solution is fine or both so I can learn more! Thank you!

Comment: Can you share some of the input data as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather straightforward solution would be to read the data as strings, and then parsing using [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html).

Sample code:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

raw_data = \
    """
    col_1,col_2
    a val,00:00:11.904
    another val,00:00:12.730
    a third val,00:00:12.430
    fourth val,00:00:15.161
    fifth val,00:00:15.354
    """

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(raw_data), header=0, dtype={"col_1": "string", "col_2": "string"})

print(f"{df}\n\n{df.dtypes}\n\n")

df["col_2"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["col_2"])

print(f"{df}\n\n{df.dtypes}")
```

Output:

```
             col_1         col_2
0            a val  00:00:11.904
1      another val  00:00:12.730
2      a third val  00:00:12.430
3       fourth val  00:00:15.161
4        fifth val  00:00:15.354

    col_1    object
col_2        string
dtype: object


             col_1           col_2
0            a val 00:00:11.904000
1      another val 00:00:12.730000
2      a third val 00:00:12.430000
3       fourth val 00:00:15.161000
4        fifth val 00:00:15.354000

    col_1             object
col_2        timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: You are correct, I was stuck on the idea of reading in the date time as the index. Once I read it is as a string and got the dataframe in the shape I wanted, I then set the index as the timestamp and it worked. Thank you!